# UrbanAirship dll for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8, urbanairship.com, mpns

Any one can you please point me where can i download the UrbanAirShip's Windows Phone 8 library. I have read the below documentation for Windows Phone 8's Push notification however i am not able to notice any link to dowload the dll for Windows Phone 8.

https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3A+Windows+8

Answer (score 0):

We can download the resources for the Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 in the below link. However  only beta version is available.

http://urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources